# Everytime i try to install something i get this error: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:

Tags: apt, dpkg

Hey everytime i try to apt install something i get an error

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 loading files list file for package 'linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33': cannot read /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33.list (Input/output error)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Try this: `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall  linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33` - it might be the remedy.